# Возможно ли подменить дату коммита на гитхаб

Tags: git, github

Допустим, я создал на github.com 01 января 2020 года репозиторий, клонировал его локально и на несколько дней забросил в таком состоянии.

И, сделав его локально 7 января хочу поменять дату на более раннюю - скажем, на второе января. Понятно, что локально можно поменять системное время как угодно, но интересует вопрос не по git, а конкретно по серверу github: получится ли при коммите 7 января сделать вид, что коммит был сделан в другую дату или технические следы скрыть не получится?

Вопрос имеет вот какую практическую ценность для меня: можно ли использовать гит в качестве юридически значимых моментов, т.е. если на гитхаб виден коммит от 2 января - то можно показать или опровергнуть даты создания коммитов локально и дату пуша на сервер гитхаб. Что-то типа как оффлайн способ "отправьте себе несколько конвертов с вашей рукописью, чтобы потом по штемпелю почтамта иметь возможность доказать своё авторство", только в цифровую эпоху.

Меня интересует именно технический аспект, насколько это возможно или невозможно. Представление о rebase имею, поэтому интересует именно понимание куда смотреть и на что обращать внимание, чтобы апеллировать к фактам типа "локальное время создания коммита" и "дата пуша на сервер гитхаба" и т.п.

Comment: А разве нельзя репозиторий скачать, локально поменять и заново залить на гитхаб?

Comment: Зависит от гитхаба, если речь только о git - на него полагаться нельзя, поменять можно) Проще всего взять и проверить)

Comment: Думаю, даты коммитов будут из гита, но где-то будут светиться и реальные даты, даты создания веток и т.п.

Comment: @vp_arth А где? Вот я бы как раз посмотрел где будет светиться и как посмотреть, не будучи администратором сервера. Это возможно?

Comment: Надо взять и запушить чего-нибудь)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дата коммита, отображаемая в интерфейсе Github, это именно дата создания коммита в git, а не дата отправки его на сервер. Она действительно может быть любой, в зависимости от локального времени (даже раньше предыдущего коммита!). То есть про "подменить" тут вопрос даже не стоит, подлинность этой даты изначально не гарантируется.

Тем не менее, узнать дату отправки коммита на сервер, если она отличается от даты создания, можно несколькими способами:

1. Локально - с помощью команды git reflog:

```
$ git reflog show origin/test  --date=iso
5d77a46 (HEAD -> test, origin/test) refs/remotes/origin/test@{2020-10-10 23:53:59 +0500}: update by push
f5ce51c refs/remotes/origin/test@{2020-10-10 23:44:11 +0500}: update by push
8965780 refs/remotes/origin/test@{2020-10-10 23:42:36 +0500}: update by push
```

Само собой, эти даты тоже можно подменить, так что в плане доказательства это ничего не дает.

2. Если у репозитория настроены задачи CI с событием `on: [push]`, то в логах CI запуск задачи для коммита будет виден именно со временем его отправки на сервер. Например, [этот коммит](https://github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/CilTools/pull/38/commits/aac526d2cee9e12a8a4add2227b0cd979c0b97bc) я локально создал в 10:08 по уральскому времени - это 5:08 GMT, а отправил на сервер в 11:53 GMT. В логах CI отображается второе время: https://github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/CilTools/runs/1235315854

[image: ci log]

Логи CI можно удалить, но подделать, насколько я знаю, нельзя, по крайней мере, при использовании стандартных VM от Github Actions.

3. Если с веткой связан Pull request, при использовании команды push -f в интерфейсе светится реальное время отправки на сервер:

[image: force push]

Благодаря этому, если было изменение/удаление коммитов, это можно обнаружить, так как при этом всегда делается force push. Но, как я уже сказал, с веткой должен быть связан Pull request, и он должен быть создан до force push.

Таким образом, есть некоторые признаки, которые позволяют обнаружить ложное время коммитов, но все они не абсолютные и вряд ли могут являться юридически значимыми. Думаю, только свой сервер Github Enterprise в полной мере решает проблему - там можно поднять логи и все увидеть.